# Multiple static assets directories in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to use express to serve static data to my application and to handle request to protected API. Let's say I have this folder structure:

```
root/
  node_modules/
  dist/
    app/
    server/
      app.js // Main server file.
  src/
    app/
    assets/
      css/
      img/
    index.html
```

I would like to get access to `node_moduels/`, `dist/app/` and `assets/` from `index.html`. It would be great if url look like this: `http://localhost:port` and `app.js` do not have to be directly in `root/`. Is it possible using `express.static()`? If yes how would you do that? And if not, what need to be changed in folder structure mentioned above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`app.js` can go anywhere.  Just reference it in your `package.json` scripts like:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "node dist/server/app.js"
},
...
```

You can have multiple static folders.  Use directories relative to `app.js`.  For example:

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../src'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../src/assets'));
```

Then you'll serve `src/index.html` and it can refer to assets in `src/assets` directly.  Even though it's possible, it's better to adjust your layout to match the way it will be served and use a single root.  In particular, serving the `node_modules` folder seems like a bad idea.  npm is for server side code, perhaps you should use bower to manage your client side packages.

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much. Turns out I was making a dumb(I forgot about slash) mistake and that is why my configuration was not working properly.